Simplifying $\lvert x-a\rvert<\lvert x-b\rvert\iff-\lvert x-b\rvert<x-a<\lvert x-b\rvert$
I am studying SECTION 1.1e, page 12; Question 1. (a) from Introduction to Calculus and Analysis by Richard Courant.
I have found two ways to solve it, but suspect that there is a more algebraic way of reasoning through this.
The question is as follows: "Using signs of inequality alone (not using signs of absolute value) specify the values of $x$ which satisfy $\lvert x-a\rvert<\lvert x-b\rvert$. Discuss all cases."
Method 2
My second solution is very straightforward, so I will go through it first. Basically, I say that the distance from $x$ to $a$ is less than the distance from $x$ to $b$. Therefore, $x$ can only exist in the interval from the midpoint of $a$ and $b$, to infinity (in the direction of $a$.) Obviously, the interval does not include the midpoint.
So, if $a<b$, then $x\in\left(-\infty,\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$
if $a=b$, then $x\in\emptyset$
and if $a>b$, then $x\in\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\infty\right)$
Method 1
My first method is "the long way". First we re-express our absolute values as piece-wise functions:
$$\lvert x-a\rvert=\left\{\begin{aligned}x-a&\quad\mbox{if }x\geq a\\a-x&\quad\mbox{if }x<a\end{aligned}\right.$$
Similarly,
$$\lvert x-b\rvert=\left\{\begin{aligned}x-b&\quad\mbox{if }x\geq b\\b-x&\quad\mbox{if }x<b\end{aligned}\right.$$
Method 1, Section 1
So, if $a<b$, then we have three intervals of interest: $\overset{(P)}{(-\infty,a)}$, $\overset{(Q)}{(a,b)}$, and $\overset{(R)}{(b,\infty)}$.
In interval (P), our inequality reduces to $a-x<b-x\iff a<b$ which is true for all $x$.
In interval (Q), our inequality reduces to $x-a<b-x\iff x<\frac{a+b}{2}$.
In interval (R), our inequality reduces to $-a<-b\iff a>b$, which is true for no $x$.
This leaves us with $x\in\left(-\infty,\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$
Method 1, Section 2
If $a=b$, then we will have two intervals of interest, $\overset{(P)}{(-\infty,a)}$ and $\overset{(Q)}{(a,\infty)}$.
In (P), our inequality reduces to $a-x<b-x$, or $a<b$. This is true for no $x$, so the set is empty. Similar is true of (Q). So, when $a=b$, $x$ occupies no values.
Method 1, Section 3
When $b<a$, the opposite of the solution for when $a<b$ holds, and $x\in\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\infty\right)$

Method 3
Now, I am interested in learning to do this purely algebraically. That is, I want to manipulate the inequality to obtain these results.
I know that $\lvert x\rvert<a\iff-a<x<a$.
So, $\lvert x-a\rvert<\lvert x-b\rvert\iff-\lvert x-b\rvert<x-a<\lvert x-b\rvert$
My question is what rule I can use to further break down this inequality.
It seems difficult to use $\lvert x\rvert>a\iff x\in(-\infty,-a)\cup(a,\infty)$ because there are three instead of two expressions in the inequality.

Appendum
Per @AnneBauva's comment, I tried using the rule separately for both inequalities, but I seem to be making a mistake because my result (seems to) contradicts itself.
For the inequality $\lvert x-a\rvert<\lvert x-b\rvert\iff-\lvert x-b\rvert<x-a<\lvert x-b\rvert$, we will break it up into
$$\overset{(A)}{-\lvert x-b\rvert<x-a};\qquad\overset{(B)}{x-a<\lvert x-b\rvert}$$
For (A), it reduces to
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}-\lvert x-b\rvert&<x-a\\\lvert x-b\rvert&>a-x\end{aligned}\right\}\implies b-x<a-x<x-b$$
For (B), it reduces simply to
$$a-x<x-b<x-a$$
So, we are left with
$$b-x<a-x<x-b<x-a$$
This seems to imply that $b$ is strictly smaller than $a$ though, because
$$b-x<a-x<x-b<x-a\iff b<a<2x-b<2x-a$$

"It seems difficult to use $\lvert x\rvert>a\iff x\in(-\infty,-a)\cup(a,\infty)$": no it is not. Use this rule separately for each of the two inequalities.

@AnneBauval Thank you for the encouragement. I seem to be getting a contradictory answer in trying this, so I will post an appendum to the question to clarify my approach.

HINT
Another possible approach:
\begin{align*}
|x - a| < |x - b| & \Longleftrightarrow |x - a|^{2} < |x - b|^{2}\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x - a)^{2} < (x - b)^{2}\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x - a)^{2} - (x - b)^{2} < 0\\
& \Longleftrightarrow [(x - a) - (x - b)][(x - a) + (x - b)] < 0\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (b - a)(2x - a - b) < 0
\end{align*}
Then consider the cases $b > a$, $b = a$ and $b < a$ separately.
Can you take it from here?

Ahh, if $a=b$, then $0<0$, and in either of the other cases, we can divide 0 by $b-a$ and obtain a simple inequality! I am still curious where my reasoning went wrong though.

$$\begin{align}(A)&\iff-\lvert x-b\rvert<x-a\\&\iff\lvert x-b\rvert>a-x
\\&\iff x-b>a-x\text{ or }x-b<x-a
\\&\iff x>\frac{a+b}2\text{ or }b>a.
\end{align}$$
Similarly,
$$(B)\iff b<a\text{ or }x<\frac{a+b}2.$$So, your third method leads to the same conclusion as the two first ones.
These "or" correspond to your "$\cup$". Your mistake was to replace them with (implicit) ands.

Thank you! I forgot to split it up using or (it's been a while). I'm going to have to practice going over this solution a bit so I can refamiliarize myself with these rules.
